# Return rows where found multiple keywords either in the same column or different columns to show those keywords along with the respected columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping someone has a quick suggestion to the following, based on the following sample table:

```
|Column1 |Column2 |Column3 |Column4 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|ABC XYZ |DFG KIL |YUI XYZ |ABC IOH |
|YDT NJK |ABC HJK |NJM XYZ |WEC OPP |
```

I was thinking to be able to build a query to search multiple words either in the same column or different columns to show those keywords and the respected columns. This, without leaning on cursors.

I.e. I would like the following output if the user search keywords `'ABC', 'YUI', 'OPP'`:

```
|Col1    |Col2    |Col3    |Col4    |Found Keyword|Keyword Found in |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------------|-----------------|
|ABC XYZ |DFG KIL |YUI XYZ |ABC IOH |ABC, YUI     |Col1,Col3,Col4   | 
|YDT NJK |ABC HJK |NJM XYZ |WEC OPP |ABC, OPP     |Col2,Col4        |
```

I've been trying to do various things like `(sys.columns, UNION ALL, CROSS JOIN)`, but so far to little avail.

There are more than 100K rows, what is the best way to do it?

Note: I'm using SQL Server 2012 version.

Comment: Can you handle this on the front end? If so, do that. it's not really what SQL Server is good at.

Comment: You *could* use a string splitter and string aggregator, however, you'd need to specifically define each of your columns in your SQL. I doubt that is your aim here; meaning you'd need to go down the Dynamic SQL statement; which isn't ideal either. I agree with @scsimon her; you'd probably be better doing this in the application (although, you could do the filtering in the DBMS). On a side note, storing delimited data is also another bad idea.

Comment: Have you looked into full text search engines?

Answer (score 0):

Argg!  This is a horrible data format.  You should not be storing multiple value in a column.  But you can use giant `case` expressions.  For instance, for the "keywords found in" result:

```
select t.*,
       stuff( (case when col1 like '%' + @word1 + '%' or col1 like '%' + @word2 + '%' or col1 like '%' + @word3'
                    then ',col1' else ''
               end) +
              (case when col2 like '%' + @word1 + '%' or col2 like '%' + @word2 + '%' or col2 like '%' + @word3'
                    then ',col2' else ''
               end) +
              (case when col3 like '%' + @word1 + '%' or col3 like '%' + @word2 + '%' or col3 like '%' + @word3'
                    then ',col3' else ''
               end), 1, 1, '') as keyword_found_in            
from t;
```

You can apply similar logic to the keywords that are found.  You can adjust the logic to take into account delimiters, if that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is already been commented that your design should be reworked.

Now, here is a query that should respond to your use case. This works by declaring the words that you search for in a subquery (which makes it quite easy to add more), and then `JOIN` with the table : basically, it is enough to check if all columns concatenated match with the searched value (assuming the space separator).

Then, the outer query does the aggregation job, using `STRING_AGG()` (available in SQL Server 2017). The part that generates the list of *columns* that matched is a bit tricky, since CSV values need to be generated manually for each record.

NB : it would be good if you had a unique column (or combination of column) to avoid mixing records when aggregating. I assumed a primary key column named `id`.

Query:

```
SELECT
    t.Col1,
    t.Col2,
    t.Col3,
    t.Col4,
    STRING_AGG(words.txt, ',') FoundKeywords,
    STRING_AGG(
        STUFF(CONCAT( 
            IIF(CONCAT(' ', t.Col1, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', words.txt, '% '), ',Col1', ''),
            IIF(CONCAT(' ', t.Col2, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', words.txt, '% '), ',Col2', ''),
            IIF(CONCAT(' ', t.Col3, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', words.txt, '% '), ',Col3', ''),
            IIF(CONCAT(' ', t.Col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', words.txt, '% '), ',Col4', '')
        ), 1, 1, ''),
        ','
    ) KeywordFoundin

FROM
    mytable t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 'ABC' txt UNION ALL SELECT 'YUI' UNION ALL SELECT 'OOP'
    ) words
        ON CONCAT(' ', t.Col1, ' ', t.Col2, ' ', t.Col3, ' ', t.col4, ' ') 
            LIKE CONCAT(' %', words.txt, '% ')
GROUP BY 
    t.id,
    t.Col1,
    t.Col2,
    t.Col3,
    t.Col4
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bda761e06c3737b230ea614d4bc7c0f4)**:

```
Col1    | Col2    | Col3    | Col4    | FoundKeywords | KeywordFoundin
:------ | :------ | :------ | :------ | :------------ | :-------------
ABC XYZ | DFG KIL | YUI XYZ | ABC IOH | ABC,YUI       | Col1,Col4,Col3
YDT NJK | ABC HJK | NJM XYZ | WEC OPP | ABC           | Col2
```

---

In SQL Server < 2017, where `STRING_AGG()` is not available, I would use a simple `SELECT` with (very lenghty) expressions to compare and concatenate the required information:

```
SELECT
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3,
    Col4,
    STUFF(CONCAT(
        IIF(CONCAT(' ', Col1, ' ', Col2, ' ', Col3, ' ', Col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'ABC', '% '), ',ABC', ''),
        IIF(CONCAT(' ', Col1, ' ', Col2, ' ', Col3, ' ', Col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'YUI', '% '), ',YUI', ''),
        IIF(CONCAT(' ', Col1, ' ', Col2, ' ', Col3, ' ', Col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'OOP', '% '), ',OOP', '')
    ), 1, 1, '') FoundKeywords,
    STUFF(CONCAT( 
        IIF(
            CONCAT(' ', Col1, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'ABC', '% ')
                OR CONCAT(' ', Col1, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'YUI', '% ')
                OR CONCAT(' ', Col1, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'OOP', '% '),
            ',Col1', 
            ''
        ),
        IIF(
            CONCAT(' ', Col2, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'ABC', '% ')
                OR CONCAT(' ', Col2, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'YUI', '% ')
                OR CONCAT(' ', Col2, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'OOP', '% '),
            ',Col2', 
            ''
        ),
        IIF(
            CONCAT(' ', Col3, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'ABC', '% ')
                OR CONCAT(' ', Col3, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'YUI', '% ')
                OR CONCAT(' ', Col3, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'OOP', '% '),
            ',Col3', 
            ''
        ),
        IIF(
            CONCAT(' ', Col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'ABC', '% ')
                OR CONCAT(' ', Col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'YUI', '% ')
                OR CONCAT(' ', Col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'OOP', '% '),
            ',Col4', 
            ''
        )
    ), 1, 1, '') KeywordFoundin
FROM mytable 
WHERE
    CONCAT(' ', Col1, ' ', Col2, ' ', Col3, ' ', col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'ABC', '% ')
    OR CONCAT(' ', Col1, ' ', Col2, ' ', Col3, ' ', col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'YUI', '% ')
    OR CONCAT(' ', Col1, ' ', Col2, ' ', Col3, ' ', col4, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', 'OOP', '% ')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ddde033b9f7e57d1bd58358d64779ec4)**

Comment: Hi, I'm using SQL Server 2012 and STRING_AGG() function is not there.
So Is there any alternative of this function?

Comment: @vibhavbhavsar: I updated my answer with a query for earlier versions of SQL Server.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. There are more than 100K rows and user can enter more than 100 keywords, so do think any other FASTER way to do it?

Comment: @vibhavbhavsar: not that I can think of... I you want a more efficient (and readable !) query, then you would need to rework your database schema...